# Error trying to install grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I installed grunt using this code:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

When I run `grunt --version` it returns me the version:

```
grunt-cli v0.1.13
```

But when I go to my project's folder and run `npm install`, it returns me those errors messages:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What I'm doing wrong? I just google it for a while and I couldn't find an answer for my question, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm install` reads and installs dependencies from a `package.json` file and has nothing to do with grunt.

`node` is telling you that you don't have a `package.json` file.

Create a `package.json` by running `npm init` and then stepping through the process.

To save dependencies to your `package.json` file, you would then run

`npm install grunt --save-dev`

where `grunt` in the above command is an example of a dependency.

Also, you haven't actually installed `grunt` - you've installed the grunt command line interface whose job is to act as an interface to the local grunt installation. You haven't installed grunt locally yet (from what you've shown).

`npm install grunt --save-dev` will install it locally for you (and save it as a dependency in your `package.json` file)